# What regex would include the word 'Index' and all lines following until a double cr or lf?

Tags: regex

I am hoping to use PDFregex to extract indexes from PDF documents to act as reference entries in a DB. The indexes (as might be expected) all begin with the word index, but end with (moslty0 double carriage returns. What regaex might I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "mostly"? Where *exactly* should the match end?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Index(.|\s)*?(?=(?:\n\r|\n|\r){2})

# Index                 --> Find `Index`
# (.|\s)*?              --> Followed by any string including linefeeds (? to make it not greedy)
# (?=(?:\n\r|\n|\r){2}) --> Stop at (the first) double linefeed:

# (?=)       --> Positive lookahead: Matches if the previous is followed by it's contents.
# (?:)       --> Non-capturing group.
# \n\r|\n|\r --> Linefeeds: Windows or LF or CR
# {2}        --> Exactly 2 of the previous.
```

Make sure you you specify that the dot `.` matches linefeeds, in your code.

Comment: That won't quite work. The dot doesn't match newlines, so it will at most match one single line. Even if you switch on dotall mode, though, it will stop at a single linefeed if that happens to be a Windows-style `\r\n` linefeed. And it will also stop at `||`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I made a few modifications. This should work, not?